# Не работает подсветка в терминале VS Code

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code

Работаю с Django и когда запускаю сервер, нет подсветки ошибки про миграции и так же не подсвечиваются пути в терминале (у других все работает), все облазил в параметрах не нашел, помогите пожалуйста